# Google Custom Search: 403 error in iOS

Tags: ios, google-api, search-engine, google-custom-search

Google Custom Search is returning this 403 error from my iPhone 7.1 app.  This is the response when run in the simulator:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

Is there a flaw in the steps below?  I’d like to establish a working CSE setup process specific to iOS apps.  The screenshots at each step will hopefully help and not confuse!

1. Create a Custom Search Engine (CSE) at https://www.google.com/cse/
2. From Setup -> Basics, get the Search engine ID.
   [image: CSE search engine ID]
3. Test the CSE at https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list

   - Set "q" to any test query terms ("foo bar") and "cx" to the Search engine ID in step 2.
   - Press "Execute" and receive your search results.  They work.  Google also provides this URL which we'll re-use in Xcode in step 8.
     [image: Google API Explorer test results]
4. To get ourselves a key for ID and billing purposes, create a new project at https://console.developers.google.com/
5. Under APIs & auth -> APIs -> Enable "Custom Search API."  No other APIs are enabled.
   [image: Developer Console APIs]
6. Under APIs & auth -> Credentials -> Create a new iOS key.
   [image: Developer Console Credentials]
   Note: I also tried a browser key and the search result returned "Error 400: Invalid Value."  I returned to the iOS key since I'm on iOS and the error seemed less severe.
7. Add to this key your bundle identifier from Xcode.
   [image: Xcode bundle identifier]
8. In Xcode make your GET request to the URL in step 3.  Replace {YOUR_API_KEY} with the key from your credentials in steps 6-7.

[image: GET request in Xcode]

NSData *response contains the error 403 shown above.  Thanks for any thoughts on what's wrong!

Comment: I am facing the same error, did you get any solution for this?

Comment: thanks for the reminder!  I answered with what worked for me.

Comment: This question did help me to figure out the complete process here is all what you ned to know to get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27039037/656600

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was missing the header field **X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier**.

```
NSString *bundleID = @"com.yourCompany.yourApp";
//...define request as above
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:bundleID forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier"];
```