# Google custom search on Android failed with error 403

Tags: android, google-custom-search

Google Custom Search is returning this 403 error from my app. This is the response when run from my phone:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project."
 }
}
```

The solution for the iOS version is given here:

[Google Custom Search: 403 error in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212412/google-custom-search-403-error-in-ios)

Thanks for any thoughts on what's wrong!

Comment: Check you are doing everything  right follow easy tutorial here. http://rptwsthi.blogspot.in/2014/11/use-google-custom-search-api.html of refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27039037/656600